# Getting trophies on save from same account on different HDD

Tags: ps3, psn, hard-drive

I have just changed my PS3 Hard Drive. Since my connection is fast and I didn't have an external drive big enough to back my drive up, I decided to only copy my saves on a USB stick and reinstall/re-download my games again. I logged back in with my PSN account and now I wonder: can I still earn trophies on them?

Comment: The way I understand how trophies work, I'd say yes. I've never changed my hard drive, though, so I can't give a definite answer.

Comment: I read somewhere they are bound to the local User,  not PSN. I remember I once copied my save to a friend's PS3 and different PSN and it blocked trophies. Game was Fishing Frenzy 2. Gotta try that.  If that works,  then all do.

Comment: Also,  I think PS Plus Saves would be almost pointless if it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **as long as** you are using *the same PlayStation Network account.*

Oh, and the 500GB hard drive I just installed is **AWESOME!**